# Can Paypal notify_url be an https?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying this out in the IPN Simulator in the sandbox and it tells me "We're sorry, we could not send an IPN."

I'm setting the IPN Handler URL to https: // [notify script].  It only gives that error message when I try to execute it.

I had tried it out in my code before this and it hadn't worked there either.

Is notify_url not permitted to be SSL/HTTPS?  The whole domain is HTTPS and I'd hate to have to figure out what to do to make ONE file http.

UPDATE:
I had been testing with our alternate domain (and we have a valid, non-self-signed cert for that domain too).  I've gotten notify_url=https://... to work using our main domain but it still won't with our alt domain.  I notice that our sandbox account email address is in the main domain.  I'm wondering if for https it requires the sandbox account email to be in the same domain as the notify_url.  Seems strange that it wouldn't apply to http.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, as long as the server has an SSL certificate signed by a recognized CA. A self-signed certificate will not do.

Update: it doesn't matter about your sandbox email account. Mine is in a different domain too.

Comment: So your problem is elsewhere. You need to log your IPN script extensively to catch its failure points. If it doesn't return a 200 status you'll get what you got.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have a problem with the IPN script itself so PayPal isn't getting a successful 200 OK response back from your server when it sends the test.

I like to setup a basic simulator of my own using an HTML form and hidden fields matching what I would expect to get back from the IPN.  Set the action to your IPN URL and then you can hit it in a browser so that the result will show up on screen for you.

Just keep in mind that when testing this way the data isn't coming from PayPal so it will not verify.  You'll need to make sure your code logic will handle that appropriately for testing purposes.

Once you've gotten rid of any problems and everything works as expected in the browser, then you can go back to the simulator for a final test from PayPal's sandbox, and assuming that's good (which it should be at that point) then you'd be ready to flip the switch and go live.

Comment: Thanks, but IPN script is good.  It works in a different configuration (see update above)

Comment: I wouldn't dismiss it.  Running on different servers can cause different problems.  Hitting in a browser will tell you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Also, have you checked the server logs for that script getting hit on the server where it's not working?

Comment: Always good to check logs!  Thanks for suggesting that!  Surprised to find 403's given in response to Paypal's POSTs.  My hitting it with a GET on a browser was 200.  Both using https.  The Paypal POST works fine using http, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you've got a router/firewall blocking traffic on that server? Might need to open up PayPal's IP addresses in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Although I resolved the issue, it doesn't make sense to me why this would do it.  Leaving the info here in case it helps anyone.

There was a typo in the user part of our email (not the domain part) in the "business" parameter (i.e. our email).  Once that was fixed, the https requests were no longer bounced with a 403.

It doesn't make sense to me because I don't see why our server would care or know about what email address we use.  I can't even accept my own answer in good faith!! If I get more clarity, I'll fill it in later.

Thanks for the help to those who attempted!!

Comment: Well that probably caused your IPN script to fail. It should check that the business is yours, among many other things, including the item and its price.